# Who is drowning in this bit of prose?

Tags: riddle

You sit by the pool to eat a meal.
Me, you can see, but won’t hear.
Go ahead, eat your lunch
And drink your light beer…

I’m drowning!!! I don’t like to whine…
I’m drowning!!! But please throw me a line!
I’m drowning!!! I’ve not got much time.
I’m drowning!!! I’m not feeling fine.

Gaze across the table at your date.
Stop pigging out, put yourself on idle.
You don’t note my importance,
But to you, I am vital!

I’m drowning!!! I’m here in this pool.
I’m drowning!!! I try to stay cool.
I’m drowning!!! But you’re being cruel.
I’m drowning!!! I need a saving tool!

You sure love your meal and date…
Only sound is chewing – no conversing speech.
I flail and try to get your attention…
But my arms are short – I cannot reach…

I’m drowning!!! I’m gasping for air.
I’m drowning!!! Dry land is somewhere!
I’m drowning!!! I won’t make it there…
I’m drowning!!! I don’t think you care…

---

*Who am I in this poem?*

**HINT:**

> That 70s Show

**SEMI-CRYPTIC HINT:**

> Heaven and hell on weekends

**MY LAST HINT LIKELY GAVE IT AWAY... BUT...**

> Poetry can be soooo ambiguous...

**Explained hints with answer:**

> **HINT CLUES:**
> That 70s Show... I guess everyone googled That 70s Show and drowning looking for the answer... it was a 70s-era Saturday morning song-break in the cartoons, by the Bod Squad... Don't Drown Your Food. 
> Heaven and hell on weekends... Black Sabbath had a song called Heaven and Hell of which the first lyrics are "Sing me a song. You're a singer." 
> Ambiguity hints: "You sit by the pool"... a pool of ketchup.  "Gaze across the table at your date"... is your date your food?  "You don't note my importance/But to you I'm vital!"  I thought this lyric would have given it away for sure... I think food is vital to one's functioning.  "You sure love your meal and date"... one in the same.

Comment: This could be the child of either of the two on a date but you wouldn't be able to definitively say that.

Comment: reminds me of a scene that could have been in the movie [Honey, I Shrunk the Kids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honey,_I_Shrunk_the_Kids), where the kids are in the pool, near drowning, while the Dad is sitting right by, on a date.

Comment: Perhaps another hint to push on ahead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: Author noted that the actual answer is "your food". Below, however, is my original guess.

The answer is: Your stomach.

You sit by the pool to eat a meal.
Me, you can see, but won’t hear.
Go ahead, eat your lunch
And drink your light beer…

> You can look down and see your stomach, but you can't hear your stomach.

I’m drowning!!! I don’t like to whine…
I’m drowning!!! But please throw me a line!
I’m drowning!!! I’ve not got much time.
I’m drowning!!! I’m not feeling fine.

> The drinking of the beer is adding water to your stomach - drowning

Gaze across the table at your date.
Stop pigging out, put yourself on idle.
You don’t note my importance,
But to you, I am vital!

> If someone doesn't have a stomach (which is a vital organ), they'd probably die. Most of us don't really care about our stomach. We just dump food and junk into it (Pigging out)

I’m drowning!!! I’m here in this pool.
I’m drowning!!! I try to stay cool.
I’m drowning!!! But you’re being cruel.
I’m drowning!!! I need a saving tool!

> Could also be drowning (figuratively) in food (as in being swamped with the food you're eating).

You sure love your meal and date…
Only sound is chewing – no conversing speech.
I flail and try to get your attention…
But my arms are short – I cannot reach…

> The sound of chewing can propagate back down the esophagus into the stomach. Flailing can describe the stomachs pulsing movements. The stomach can't hear speech even if it was occurring on the date since sound propagates outwards of the mouth and not backwards. A stomach doesn't really have arms, so of course it can't reach - but reach what?

I’m drowning!!! I’m gasping for air.
I’m drowning!!! Dry land is somewhere!
I’m drowning!!! I won’t make it there…
I’m drowning!!! I don’t think you care…

> Digesting the food being gasping for air since it's so full.

Comment: you are soooo close... i guess i'll have to accept this one... here is a final chorus... I'm drowning!  But you're being crude.  I'm drowning!  Why are you so rude?  I'm drowning!  Oh c'mon, please, dude... I'm drowning!  I'm your food!!!

Comment: @ThomasRoadDawgBrakeline Oh, your food... That's a good one.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is

> The water in the pool

You sit by the pool to eat a meal.
Me, you can see, but won’t hear.
Go ahead, eat your lunch
And drink your light beer…

> You can see all the water in the pool, but it makes no noise to attract attention.

I’m drowning!!! I don’t like to whine…)
I’m drowning!!! But please throw me a line!
I’m drowning!!! I’ve not got much time.
I’m drowning!!! I’m not feeling fine.

> Every drop of water is drowning in the rest of the water in the pool. Perhaps the water is not feeling fine because it's claustrophobic and surrounded by so many like itself.

Gaze across the table at your date.
Stop pigging out, put yourself on idle.
You don’t note my importance,
But to you, I am vital!

> As you eat a lot, your throat starts to clog up and you need to take a sip of water. Water, in general, is very important to our survival.

I’m drowning!!! I’m here in this pool.
I’m drowning!!! I try to stay cool.
I’m drowning!!! But you’re being cruel.
I’m drowning!!! I need a saving tool!

> Water is everywhere in the pool, and usually there are cooling systems employed in the pool to keep the water at a cool comfortable temperature in hot weather.

You sure love your meal and date…
Only sound is chewing – no speech.
I flail and try to get your attention…
But my arms are short – I cannot reach…

> The water keeps so splish splashing at the edge of the pool, but cannot really create a big wave to reach out to you sitting in the distance.

I’m drowning!!! I’m gasping for air.
I’m drowning!!! Dry land is somewhere!
I’m drowning!!! I won’t make it there…
I’m drowning!!! I don’t think you care…

> The pool is filled with water and no air. There is dry land close to the pool but the water won't reach there. And you don't care because the water is right where it's supposed to be.

Comment: Nope.  Keep guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be:

> Chlorine?

You sit by the pool to eat a meal. 
Me, you can see, but won’t hear. 
Go ahead, eat your lunch 
And drink your light beer…

I’m drowning!!! I don’t like to whine… 
I’m drowning!!! But please throw me a line! 
I’m drowning!!! I’ve not got much time. 
I’m drowning!!! I’m not feeling fine.

> Pool water requires chlorine in it to make the water safe to swim in. You know it is there as you look into the water, but you certainly can't here it. Of course, chlorine might not be so comfortable being in a giant pool...

Gaze across the table at your date. 
Stop pigging out, put yourself on idle. 
You don’t note my importance, 
But to you, I am vital!

I’m drowning!!! I’m here in this pool. 
I’m drowning!!! I try to stay cool. 
I’m drowning!!! But you’re being cruel. 
I’m drowning!!! I need a saving tool!

> As you gaze out and admire at how handsome/pretty your boyfriend/girlfriend look, you might not notice the science of chlorine that might be used to help make the clothes your date is wearing right now (and even you)! Source: http://chlorine.americanchemistry.com/Style

You sure love your meal and date… 
Only sound is chewing – no conversing speech. 
I flail and try to get your attention… 
But my arms are short – I cannot reach…

I’m drowning!!! I’m gasping for air. 
I’m drowning!!! Dry land is somewhere! 
I’m drowning!!! I won’t make it there… 
I’m drowning!!! I don’t think you care…

> Chlorine atoms are really small. Naturally, you cannot see them since they are usually in liquid (clear) or even gas form.

Full source: http://chlorine.americanchemistry.com/Chlorine-Benefits

Comment: No, sorry.  Ummm... I'll try to think of another hint...